# Trying to Track Down Where JSON Dictionary Value Needs to Be Implemented iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, dictionary, url-routing

I have the following method which is creating a URL to an image:

```
-(NSURL*)urlForImageWithId:(NSNumber*)IdPhoto isThumb:(BOOL)isThumb {
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@upload/%@%@.jpg",
                       kAPIHost, kAPIPath, IdPhoto, (isThumb)?@"-thumb":@""
                       ];
return [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
}
```

I need to update the path to include the `IdUser` value that is associated with said image.  Here is the way that I have attempted this:

```
-(NSURL*)urlForImageWithId:(NSNumber*)IdPhoto isThumb:(BOOL)isThumb {
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@upload/%@/%@%@.jpg",
                       kAPIHost, kAPIPath, IdUser, IdPhoto, (isThumb)?@"-thumb":@""
                       ];
return [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
}
```

When I tried to do this, xcode says “Declare `IdUser`,” so I did.  I Added this to the `.h`

`@property (assign, nonatomic) NSNumber* IdUser;`

and I added this below implementation:

`@synthesize IdUser;`

but when I run the program I get a `null` value for `IdUser`.

When I log the dictionary like this:

`NSLog(@"Result from Stream: %@",json);`

I get the following output:

```
result =     (
            {
        IdPhoto = 5;
        IdUser = 7;
        title = this is the title;
        username = presto;
    });
}
```

as one example.  Here you can clearly see that the `IdUser` value is being passed through the dictionary.  My guess is that the `IdPhoto` from `-(NSURL*)urlForImageWithId:(NSNumber*)IdPhoto isThumb:(BOOL)isThumb {`
must be defined somewhere else.  Any idea on what I should look for to track this down and be able to pull that `IdUser` value over as well?

Comment: Where are you interpreting the JSON and setting the properties?  Objective-C is not Java and we don't cotton to that fancy Jackson stuff.  You copy the values from the JSON-generated dictionary to your object yourself, the way &deity intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding a property does not set the value of that property.  Where is `self.IdUser` being initiated?  It sounds like you are confusing a key of a dictionary with a `ViewController` property.

Try this to see if that is the case (do this after you get that `NSArray` named json).

```
NSDictionary *dict = [json objectAtIndex:0];
self.IdUser = [dict objectForKey:@"IdUser"];
NSLog(@"self.IdUser = %@", self.IdUser];
```

Comment: I am getting this error message `no visible @interface for 'NSDictionary'...`

Comment: Post the actual result of that log statement you have in the original post.  It could be that json is a Dictionary of Dictionary's.

Comment: I just added the method that produces the log result where I was attempting to add your solution.  It should be noted that this is on a separate `.m` file from where I am trying to use the `IdUser` to create the image url.  Let me know if there is any other code that would help clear this up.  Thanks.

Comment: ok... I am at the final step here.  Please see my recent update as you will see that I have been able to pull the value I need out in an earlier method on the same `.m` file.  I just need a way to globally declare it and use in the lower method.

Comment: I figured it out... thanks.  I am awarding to you since your solution pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Good to hear.  Might want to amend your question and post the solution you came up with.

Answer (score 0):

if idUser is an instance variable, you need to write it as _IdUser or self.IdUser.

Also try: [_idUser stringValue] inside the NSString stringWithFormat method to get the correct type as you specified it as a string ("@").

Comment: Just tried `NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@upload/[_idUser stringValue]/%@%@.jpg",kAPIHost, kAPIPath,IdPhoto(isThumb)?@"-thumb":@""];` but that killed the whole URL.  I may have misunderstood the suggestion.

Comment: try this: NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@upload/%@/%@%@.jpg",
                       kAPIHost, kAPIPath, [IdUser stringValue], IdPhoto, (isThumb)?@"-thumb":@""
                       ];